# Is it safe to bounce the barbell from the chest at bottom of bench press?

Tags: bench-press

I've seen a lot of power lifters do this when risking very heave load. I would like to ask, is this actually safe? What are some possible risks involved?

Self research effort: I looked up google and effort and coudl see no scientific discussion of the same.

Comment: You’ve probably not seen many actual powerlifters doing this, since it would result in no lift in competition.

Comment: And what research have you done to look into this? What did you find when you searched for information on this question yourself? Why didn’t the sources you found answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

As the above comments state, in competition the lift would be disqualified and so it shouldn't be done whether its safe or not.

As for doing it during training, if you're doing it out of necessity then you have too much weight on the bar. You probably aren't going injure you're chest with the bar but the fact that you're most likely lifting too much weight means you are at a much greater risk of injuring the pectoral muscles and also the shoulder joints through bad form.

It's also important to note that trying to lift more than you can move with proper form and controlled movement is ineffective. 3 or 4 reps with controlled movement, proper form, and even tension will be far more beneficial than 1 struggled rep with bad form that could possibly even cause injury thus hindering further sets.

Comment: The possible injuries that can result from the bouncing include a cracked sternum, a dislocated rib and in very rare cases commotio cordis.  None are *likely* but all are possible, especially if you are using very heavy weight and lack of control.